# Convert Google Analytics cookies to Local/Session Storage

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, monkeypatching, httpcookie

**UPDATE**
http://jsfiddle.net/musicisair/rsKtp/embedded/result/

---

Google Analytics sets 4 cookies that will be sent with all requests to that domain (and ofset its subdomains). From what I can tell no server actually uses them **directly**; they're only sent with `__utm.gif` as a query param.

Now, obviously Google Analytics reads, writes and acts on their values and they will need to be available to the GA tracking script.

So, what I am wondering is if it is possible to:

- rewrite the `__utm*` cookies to local storage after `ga.js` has written them
- delete them after `ga.js` has run
- rewrite the cookies FROM local storage back to cookie form right before `ga.js` reads them
- start over

Or, **monkey patch `ga.js` to use local storage before it begins the cookie read/write part.**

Obviously if we are going so far out of the way to remove the `__utm*` cookies we'll want to also use the Async variant of Analytics.

I'm guessing the down vote was because I didn't ask a question. DOH!

**My questions are:

Can it be done as described above?

If so, why hasn't it been done?**

---

*I have a default `HTML/CSS/JS` boilerplate template that passes YSlow, PageSpeed, and Chrome's Audit with near perfect scores. I'm really looking for a way to squeeze those remaining cookie bytes from Google Analytics in browsers that support local storage.*

Comment: +1 for the well described case

Comment: I'm wondering, local storage cookies is bound to one browser session right? So if the user, for an example, visits the same page in two different tabs (in the same browser) she will count as two visitors?

Comment: The data in `LocalStorage` is persistent and doesn't expire. Also, I see that you are pretty new here... comments like the one you posted above should be posted as a comment on the question, not as an answer. :-)

Comment: This seems like a really good idea. One use case I can think of is if you have a reverse proxy / CDN in front of your site that falls back (origin pull) if the page is not static. Such a proxy might see a unique cookie, and therefore pull from origin, rather than use the cached copy of the page it already has.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch What would be the simplest way in your JSfiddle of testing if Google Analytics has worked? I'd like to see if this approach can be adapted to get GA working on content that has been embedded into 3rd party iframes on browsers that by default block cookies for 3rd party domains (Safari and Internet Explorer).

Comment: **Warning,** this idea appears to be flawed: please read https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1444#issuecomment-57235840

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use this:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

if(window.localStorage) {
    ga('create', 'UA-98765432-1', 'www.example.com', {
      'storage': 'none'
      , 'clientId': window.localStorage.getItem('ga_clientId')
    });
    ga(function(tracker) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('ga_clientId', tracker.get('clientId'));
    });
}
else {
    ga('create', 'UA-98765432-1', 'www.example.com');
}
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

First, I check if `localStorage` is supported. If it is supported then the `'storage': 'none'` option will disable cookies. Now we can set the clientId from localStorage. If it is empty, Google Analytics will generate a new one for us. We save the new (or existing) clientid in localStorage after the tracker loads.

If `localStorage` is not supported, I just use the regular analytics method. After the initialization I send a pageView via `ga('send', 'pageView')`.

Also, check out this plunk: http://plnkr.co/MwH6xwGK00u3CFOTzepK

Comment: Great job. For most cases you'd want to feature-test for localStorage first (maybe using Modernizr, falling back to cookie storage if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Could you explain what the purpose of this code is? Is there something wrong with GA's cookies?

Comment: @DavidMurdoch I see. I wonder why GA does not come with `localStorage` support built-in. (Btw, you have to *mention* me :). `@S` didn't trigger the auto-complete for my name?)

Comment: @DavidMurdoch I added 'localStorage' detection for you!

Comment: Unfortunately, just checking if `window.localStorage` is truthy is not enough. Modernizr has a stable feature test with comments explaining why it needs to be done the way they do it here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/storage/localstorage.js

Comment: A warning: HTML5 boilerplate is working on integrating this, but have experienced certain issues. The entire thread, but at least the comment https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1444#issuecomment-37852487 is worth a read.

Comment: **This might violate GA TOS!**  Here is a secondhand quote from a GA Team member, taken from [this article](http://goo.gl/sVnWBQ): *"Using HTTP State Management mechanisms" (read: localStorage) "to propagate cookie state is a circumvention of our privacy safeguards. Doing so violates the Google Analytics Terms of Service".*  My interpretation of this is that GA employs cookies and not localStorage because more users are familiar with the concept of cookies and how to clear them; thus, GA's use of cookies is a privacy feature.

Comment: While this is technically correct, the idea appears to be wrong: @DavidMurdoch please read https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1444#issuecomment-57235840

Comment: Thanks... But that github comment is actually directed at me. I am David Murdoch.

Comment: @smhmic It is officially supported by Google now! see: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1444#issuecomment-213000510

Comment: @DavidMurdoch Well, that clears up one ambiguous aspect of the GA TOS clause "You must not circumvent any privacy features".  Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2):

Some experimentation in chrome shows that it may be possible to use getters and setters to patch `document.cookie` for this, something like:

```
document.__defineGetter__('cookie', function () {
    // Replace this with code to read from localstorage
    return "hello";
});
document.__defineSetter__('cookie', function (value) {
    // Replace this with code to save to localstorage
    console.log(value);
});
```

ga.js (or any other javascript) could run and access cookies as normal, they just would never get passed to the server.

Obviously this will only work in some browsers. Browsers in which it doesn't work will have to fall back to normal cookies.

There's some related ideas in this question: [Is it possible to mock document.cookie in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456429/is-it-possible-to-mock-document-cookie-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. You only have to request the `__utm.gif` with the parameters. The rest of the data is just used for keeping track of the source, session start time and/or previous visits.

You can easily transfer the cookies both ways, so your first approach should work fine.

If your second approach works... not sure. I don't know the `ga.js` code good enough to estimate wheter that would or would not be easily possible.

There is also a third option, run your own version of `ga.js`. You are not required to use the Google version.

*Can it be done as described above?*
Yes

*Why hasn't it been done?*

1. the cookies are small, there isn't that much benefit if you use cookieless domains for all your static content
2. it's less convenient since a lot of browsers don't support it yet