# Setting a cookie on the request with chai

Tags: javascript, cookies, chai

Consider following code:

```
    it('Test logout', function (done) {
    async.each(config.www, function (url, callback) {
        var healthCheck = url + '/'
        chai.request(url).get('/')
            .then(function (res) {
                expect(res, healthCheck).to.have.status(200);
                expect(res.text.indexOf(url + '/logout?type=user">Log out</a>'), 'Logout is incorrect').to.be.greaterThan(0);
                callback();
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                callback(err);
            })
    }, done);
});
```

The problem is that I need to set a cookie to bypass a splash-page.
Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456429/is-it-possible-to-mock-document-cookie-in-javascript

Comment: not quite sure on how to add it to the request.

Comment: Hi, haven't tried it, but I'm guessing you have to create the cookie before the request as part of the setup for the test ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should work:

```
chai.request(url)
    .get('/')
    .set('Cookie', 'cookieName=cookieValue;otherName=otherValue')
    .then(...)
```

Cookies are send to the server as headers value on "Cookie" key, so you just have set them manually.

It works for me with mocha and chai-http, and i was able to recive the cookie values in my koajs v2 app

Answer (score 0):

To augment Pedro's answer I needed to set the session ID into the cookie. To do this I generated the cookie data with stringify on the inner object and using "cookieName=".

```
const cValue = "cookieName=" + JSON.stringify({sessionId: sessionId});
chai.request(url)
    .get("/userData")
    .set('Cookie', cValue);
    .then(...)
```