# How to mock cookies with QUnit and Sinon?

Tags: javascript, sinon, qunit

I have this code:

```
var CookieHelper = function () {
    return {
        GetCookie : function (cookieName) {
            var cookieNameRequest = cookieName + "=";
            var cookiesCollection = document.cookie.split(";");
            for (var i = 0; i < cookiesCollection.length; i++) {
                var cookieValuePair = cookiesCollection[i];
                while (cookieValuePair.charAt(0) == " ") cookieValuePair = cookieValuePair.substring(1, cookieValuePair.length);
                if (cookieValuePair.indexOf(cookieNameRequest) == 0)
                    return cookieValuePair.substring(cookieNameRequest.length, cookieValuePair.length);
            }
            return null;
        },

        DeleteCookie : function (cookieName) {
            CookieHelper.SetCookie(cookieName, "", -1);
        },

        SetCookie : function (cookieName, cookieValue, cookieExpirationDays) {
            var tmpDate = new Date;
            if (cookieExpirationDays) {
                tmpDate.setTime(tmpDate.getTime() + cookieExpirationDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                var expires = "; expires=" + tmpDate.toGMTString();
            } else {
                // if cookieExpirationDays isn't set cookie will expire at the end of the day
                var expirationTime = new Date(tmpDate.getFullYear(), tmpDate.getMonth(), tmpDate.getDate(), 23, 59, 59);
                var expires = "; expires=" + expirationTime.toGMTString();
            }
            document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + expires + "; path=/;" + (location.protocol === "https:" ? "secure=true" : "");
        }
    };
}();
```

and I need to write unit tests for GetCookie. 
I tried with:

```
QUnit.module('Cookie Helper Tests');

QUnit.test('GetCookie - returns no cookie', function(assert) {
    var stub = sinon.spy(CookieHelper, 'GetCookie');

    var cookieName = 'testCookieName';
    var cookieValue = CookieHelper.GetCookie(cookieName);

    assert.ok(cookieValue == null, 'returns no cookie');    
});
```

I need to mock/stub document.cookie but I am completely new with Sinon and QUnit.
Can someone give me explanation what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance!
Srdjan

Comment: According to your test results, there is nothing wrong since it passes :)  What exactly do you want to know?  How to return a response from a stub? Please be specific.

Comment: I don't want to call document.cookie because this is specific for browser.

Comment: So I have to find a way to stub document property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well actually you can't mock properties with Sinon and more over you cannot mock the **document.cookies** property as it's immutable.  What you can do though, is to use a fake double object that mimics the behavior of the original object, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456429/is-it-possible-to-mock-document-cookie-in-javascript).

For example, if you were running the same test outside of the browser (e.g. in NodeJS) you would do something like that

```
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const SinonChai = require('sinon-chai');

chai.use(SinonChai);
chai.should();

context('test', function() {


  it('should pass',
    (done) => {

      var cookieName = 'testCookieName';

      document = {
        cookie: cookieName + '=123'
      };

      var cookieValue = CookieHelper.GetCookie(cookieName);

      console.log(cookieValue);

      done();
    });

});
```

in order to introduce a **document** object to the context and mimic it's cookies attribute by returning a fixed result.

Now, there is a workaround for the browser which involves redefining the getter and setter of 'document.cookie' as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16194633/2459094):

```
(function (document) {
    var cookies = {};
    document.__defineGetter__('cookie', function () {
        var output = [];
        for (var cookieName in cookies) {
            output.push(cookieName + '=' + cookies[cookieName]);
        }
        return output.join(';');
    });
    document.__defineSetter__('cookie', function (s) {
        var indexOfSeparator = s.indexOf('=');
        var key = s.substr(0, indexOfSeparator);
        var value = s.substring(indexOfSeparator + 1);
        cookies[key] = value;
        return key + '=' + value;
    });
    document.clearCookies = function () {
        cookies = {};
    };
})(document);
```