# Prevent 3rd party script from setting cookies (specifically Google adsense)

Tags: javascript, cookies, adsense

In light of Google's decision to force publishers to ask permission to set cookies onto visitors from the EU, I was talking with their support, and somehow I think I got the hint without them saying in so many words that it might be possible to prevent 3rd party scripts from setting cookies and be done with it.

[My alternative is to just not show Adsense in the EU anymore, I'll not do any "ask for permission to set cookies" pop-up]

What I seek to do:

- prevent cookies being set by google's unmodified javascript. I was hoping to overload something??
  FWIW: AFAIK Google uses document.write to create an iframe, so it might be harder.
- run the ads - and have them working as intended without setting a cookie
- NOT bother visitors with asking for permission

[I already can geotarget the EU quite accurately, so that's covered]

Comment: There is a way for [google analytics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668292/is-there-a-setting-on-google-analytics-to-suppress-use-of-cookies-for-users-who) so might be something similar for adsense

Comment: Thanks gillesc, but that's the google analytics script honoring a variable to not work at all. FWIW: I plan on trashing analyics and running my own stuff for what I need - I hardly use most of what GA offers anyway, and the little I do use is easy enough to replicate I think.