# Correct (technically) handling of cookie consent

Tags: cookies, browser

I'm about to implement cookie consent for a website. As I understand it, cookie consent means that you shall not use cookies before you have received a consent from the user.

How can I know that a user have accepted cookies or not without storing this information in a cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the GDPR. Your understanding of it is incomplete: cookies that are necessary to deliver the site's functionality are allowed without consent. A cookie that merely stores consent is thus allowed, even if the user rejected other cookies.

I am not a lawyer, not legal advice, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I sugest you set a cookie only if the user has accepted cookies. If this cookie is set dont ask again. Otherwise show the cookie consent banner again and again on every new site they visit as if they were new visitors.

What i find strange is that even big german sites like Stern.de, Focus.de, Spiegel,de and even the computer magazine heise.de are setting loads of cookies before they show the consent banner.

Even more strange is that while Stern.de and Focus.de also offer a complicate "Adjust" button (users usuarly dont click them because adjusting cookie preferences on every site is nerve wrecking), Spiegel.de and Heise.de dont even offer this. They just offer "Accept" or pay for a ad free version.

If you click on "Adjust" instead of "Accept" on the first sites they just close the consent banner.

So all the sites dont show a button to easily denie or delete cookies even i thought it has to be as easy to deny as to accept. Im not a lawyer too and this is no legal advice but if they all do it this way i guess this must be legal in Germany even it doesnt make any sence at all. Cookies are set no matter what the visitor does. The big question seems to be what es necessary? Are google Analytics und Adsense and others necessary to finance the server and keep the site online? Necessary cookies are allowed.

Writing this, there is an article in another big news site (that also sets loads of cookies before showing the consent banner and also just offers accept or pay buttons) saying someone had to pay €100 for not asking the visitor for his permission before even loading google fonts not even talking about analytics: https://t3n.de/news/google-fonts-illegal-urteil-dsgvo-1447698/

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/q/70967060/12668719

Analytics [Is there a setting on Google Analytics to suppress use of cookies for users who have not yet given consent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668292/is-there-a-setting-on-google-analytics-to-suppress-use-of-cookies-for-users-who/70973409#70973409)

Adsense [How To Make Adsense Load When Cookie Consent Given?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729701/how-to-make-adsense-load-when-cookie-consent-given/70958220#70958220)

Comment: This is the preferred answer for people who want to promote ad/cookie/consent blockers.

Answer (score 0):

Information about accepting cookies should be saved in local storage.

[See the differences between cookies and local storage.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3220660/14023394)

Additionally, if you accept cookies in 2024+, you will probably be interested in how to save cookies so that Google allows functionalities such as Google Analytics. Below is an example of implementation in JS.

```js
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}

let cookieConsent = {
    functionality: true,
    security: true,
    analytics: false,
    marketing: false,
    preferences: false
};

const consentMode = {
    'functionality_storage': cookieConsent.functionality ? 'granted' : 'denied',
    'security_storage': cookieConsent.security ? 'granted' : 'denied',
    'analytics_storage': cookieConsent.analytics ? 'granted' : 'denied',
    'ad_storage': cookieConsent.marketing ? 'granted' : 'denied',
    'personalization': cookieConsent.preferences ? 'granted' : 'denied',
};

gtag('consent', 'update', consentMode);
localStorage.setItem('consentMode', JSON.stringify(consentMode));
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this open source solutionfor the EU cookie law compliance:

https://cookieconsent.osano.com/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The advertised specific solution might implement cookie consent, but an answer should explain e.g. if and which cookies are allowed or not, etc.. If necessary, the link may still be added with a comment like "...as you can see in libraries like this one".

Answer (score -1):

The easiest and most effective way is to show a pop-up banner that explains which kind of cookies you want to store and provide an option to allow/disallow each cookie. When clicking Save, you have to handle which cookies were allowed and load them accordingly. Everything can be done in JS.