# Code to disable Google Analytics / Adwords cookie until user confirms they accept cookies?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I found [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801416/disabling-cookies-in-google-analytics-gtag-js) but I was wondering if there are other ways I could delay GA setting the cookies? That code wasn't clear to me at all, so I'm suspicious of it. How sensitive is the analytics code to being tampered with? Google suggests the code needs to be the first thing in the head tag, so I'm wondering if modifications to it would interfere with its functionality?

The code looks like this:

```
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-**********"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-**********');
</script>
```

The code for Adwords is similar:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-1068746090"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'AW-1068746090');
</script>
```

Comment: Why bothering with gtag when there's GTM?

Comment: @BNazaruk what's GTM? I just copied code as per Google's instructions, I presumed it was up to date

Comment: Wow. Okay. You surely can implement tracking and consent management through the code, working directly with gtag. But it's definitely not the best practice especially for web  apps. The best practice is to load Google Tag Manager instead of installing gtag and let GTM handle all the libraries exactly when they're needed. Have all your logic deployed in GTM through its UI rather than in code. It makes it much much easier to maintain, scale and support through time. Consent management in GTM is, too, much easier than in gtag. GTM has way more options for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Google suggests the code needs to be the first thing in the head tag, so I'm wondering if modifications to it would interfere with its functionality?

Actually it does not matter where you put the code. The earlier/higher you put it the earlier the browser will load it, execute it and send a pageview.

If you prefer page performance (e.g. web core vitals) over misleading tracking, you can replace the async attribute with a defer attribute which will cause GA to load later (e.g. after your page is "ready").

I prefer deferring GA. For us there is no point in measuring pageviews which bounce even before the page is "ready".

Please take into consideration that if you use both - GA4 and AW - the code would look like

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'G-XXX');
  gtag('config', 'AW-00');
</script>
```

You do not include it twice.

There's documentation from Google for [Consent Mode](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/devguides/consent) and about [Privacy](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/devguides/privacy)

Your code would look like this:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('consent', 'default', {
    'ad_storage': 'denied',
    'analytics_storage': 'denied'
  });
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'G-XXX');
  gtag('config', 'AW-00');
</script>
```

And here's a brief walkthrough:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXX"></script>
```

This loads the tracking code/library. Once it is loaded, it will override the `dataLayer.push` method and process all entries of the dataLayer array (if there are any). If you would only have this line of markup, nothing would happen. No cookies, no tracking.

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
```

This is some precaution. We cannot be sure if the tracking code/library has been loaded and executed (and declared the dataLayer variable), so we check if dataLayer is undefined. If is undefined we initialize it as an empty array.

```
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
```

For easier usage and/or branding we wrap the `dataLayer.push()` method call in a function called `gtag`. You [could use](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/renaming-the-gtag-object) cl22 or timw instead, it would not matter.

```
gtag('consent', ...
```

If you would inspect dataLayer now, it would look like this:

```
[
    [
        "consent",
        "default",
        {
            "ad_storage": "denied",
            "analytics_storage": "denied"
        }
    ]
]
```

If `push` method was already overridden by GA4, this would have been already executed. If not it would sit there and wait until GA4 loads.

```
gtag('js', new Date());
```

This creates a timestamp.

```
gtag('config', 'G-XXX');
```

This will initialize tracking. In default setups, this will send a page_view event. Here GA4 would set its cookies, but because of our previous "entry" it won't.

```
gtag('config', 'AW-00');
```

This will initialize AdWords.