# UTM tags are disappeared after hitting my website url

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics, utm, campaign-monitor

I have google analytics account, i have added analytics code in my index.html. But Mycampaign tag in google analytics is not showing any data. I have user google URL builder to generate campaign url. What could be the problem?

```
1. UTM tags disappeared on landing page of website
2. analytics code may have some changes
```

here is the analytic code added in index.html, i am using UA(Universal analytics)

```
<script>
    (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
        i[r] = i[r] || function() {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
        a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
        a.async = 1;
        a.src = g;
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: The code works properly, i've tested and you have no personalisation at least on the code show.

Comment: @KemenPaulosPlaza  but it is not giving campaign detail

Comment: How says the guys below, the code it's working properly.
Lets start to discard option 
First use the url tag assistant https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en
Then check your filters, and in the last place try to change the UA in a Dev's enviorement. It look likes an configuration issue

Comment: actually , i have no domain name, its working  on an Ip address on cloud. could it be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you're executing this on localmachine or in a Web with no domain this can be a problem, the Google Analytics  Universal das dependencies with the domain (sometimes this no happens but well), so you can try to change the

```js
ga('create','UA-1-1','auto');
```

for

```js
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {
'cookieDomain': 'none'
});
```

or look for other options on this thread:
[Can you test google analytics on a localhost address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375447/can-you-test-google-analytics-on-a-localhost-address)

Warn us if this help your issue

Comment: still it is not showing all campaign data, in link provided by you, it says that it will give instant result, but still i would like to wait 24 hrs

Comment: Would mean that is not the origin of the issue. Because realtime shows instant data. The other common error related with this is when you change domains jumping from https to https.
To be honest,in this case i think that we need more information, to explore the tool and determine theorigin. i dont know for example the sessions/user (to  see if exist sessions cut). Also you can check is the Referal Domain Exclusion is properly configurated or the posibility to change to localstorage . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502128/convert-google-analytics-cookies-to-local-session-storage

Answer (score 0):

Might help if you posted the tagged URL. I know you used the URL builder but it still could be incorrect. Also, if you're looking at a filtered view in Analytics you won't see all traffic. Check that the tag is firing using Google Tag Assistant.

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide an example page that has this issue, it would be helpful.  Then we can look closely at your UTM parameters and also you GA javascript.